# Difference between proving algebra and sigma-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing

I wonder what differs in the proof methodology when it comes to proving a set is an algebra vs proving a set is an sigma-algebra. For instance, take these three questions (ignoring monotone classes)
[image]

When I prove that a set is a sigma-algebra, I would use the same method as when I prove a set is an algebra, only changing finite unions $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^k$ to countable unions $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}$. Beside that, everything would stay the same in my opinion.

Am I missing something out? Is there something else I need to keep in mind when I prove it's an sigma-algebra instead of an algebra?

**Note**: I'm **not** asking for anyone to prove the statements for me, I'm just confused about the proof methodology between the exercises.

Comment: I would have thought closure under countable unions is what makes an algebra over a set be a sigma-algebra so is the only additional thing you need to check.

Comment: Perhaps it is that easy and I'm overthinking it. Thanks @Henry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say for example you have proven $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra on a set $X$. This means that $\mathcal{A}$ already contains $\emptyset$ and $X$, closed under complement and closed under finite union. The only extra condition that you will want to check when proving $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ is then it is closed under countable union.

The thing is, you are in fact asking a lot more when claiming closure under countable union. Take for example the collection of subsets $\mathcal{A} := \{ \bigcup_{i = 1} ^n C_i \times D_i \subseteq C \times D: C_i \in \mathcal{C}, D_i \in \mathcal{D}, n \in \mathbf{N} \}$ on the set $C \times D$ with $(C, \mathcal{C})$ and $(D, \mathcal{D})$ being two measurable spaces. It is clearly not closed under countable union and thus not a $\sigma$-algebra. However, $\mathcal{A}$ is indeed an algebra as one can check through definition (in particular, $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under finite union).